# Filter_validate_email not working on live server but fine on localhost

Tags: php, email

I'm using php's FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL to check if an email is in correct format.
When I was still working on xampp on my local machine it worked fine (php 5.5).
After uploading it to a live server I keep getting "email invalid" message whether the email is correct or not (checked php 5.3, 5.5 and 5.6).

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
     //Variables used for registering
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);   
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $submit = $_POST['register'];
        $joindate = date("y.m.d");
        //Get data from database to check if a user exists

        $userssql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");

        if(isset($submit)) {
            if(mysql_num_rows($userssql) == 0) {
                if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    $encryptpass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    $register = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users(username, email, password, joindate) VALUES('$username', '$email', '$encryptpass', '$joindate')");
                    header("location: login.php");
                }
                else {
                 ?>
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                  $('#email-error').text("Invalid email");
                 </script>
                            <?php
                }
            }
            else {
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#username-error').text("Username already exists");
                </script>
                <?php 
            }     
        }
    ?>
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Aside from the fact that you're using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions, you're also using `mysqli_query` - this obviously won't work. Perhaps you're mistaken about the cause of your problems.

Comment: Cheers Robbie for pointing this out. I was in the middle of changing it but didn't know mysqli_real_escape_string requires two parameters. I need to rewrite most of my site now. Thanks mate.